# Using Pi Model B as an access point

Tags: pi-2, wifi, ethernet

I want to connect my Model B to my university network, which I can do using the ethernet connection; this should be simple to do. What I am unsure of is how I can then use the Pi to act as an access point for this network; I want to connect an amazon echo dot to it, which will then be able to work off of this connection, as I cannot connect the echo directly to the university WiFi. I won't be able to edit any settings of the network that is providing the ethernet, and I have a WiFi dongle for the model B.

Alternative suggestions for getting the Echo connected using an ethernet solution would be appreciated if they are simpler, though I recognise that that could be marked as off topic.

Comment: See the following list from a google search. https://www.google.com/search?q=using+a+raspberry+pi+as+a+network+access+point&rlz=1C1CHZL_enUS733US733&oq=using+a+raspberry+pi+as+a+network+access+point&aqs=chrome..69i57.8995j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 looks to be lots of documentation on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Raspberrypi.org has the best most simple answers:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md